# C++11 rvalue reference addressing

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

I'm trying to understand the c++11 move semantics, and created the following sandbox project:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "my-class.h"
#include <iostream>

MyOtherClass getRValue(void)
{
  MyOtherClass retVal;
  std::cout << "Address of getRValue local var is " << &retVal << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Returning from getRValue...\n";
  return retVal;
}

int main()
{
  MyClass bar(getRValue());
  std::cout << "Address of bar member is " << &(bar.getObjRef()) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

**my-class.h**

```
#ifndef MY_CLASS_H_INCLUDED
#define MY_CLASS_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>

class MyOtherClass
{
private:
  int somePOD;
  char someOtherPOD;

public:
  MyOtherClass(void);
  MyOtherClass(MyOtherClass const& argOther);
  MyOtherClass(MyOtherClass&& argOther);
};

class MyClass
{
private:
  MyOtherClass obj;

public:
  MyClass(MyOtherClass&& arg);
  MyOtherClass& getObjRef(void);
};

#endif // MY_CLASS_H_INCLUDED
```

**my-class.cpp**

```
#include "my-class.h"

// Class MyOtherClass
MyOtherClass::MyOtherClass(void)
: somePOD(42), someOtherPOD('x')
{
  std::cout << "MyOtherClass c'tor called.\n";
}
MyOtherClass::MyOtherClass(MyOtherClass const& argOther)
{
  std::cout << "MyOtherClass copy c'tor called.\n";
}
MyOtherClass::MyOtherClass(MyOtherClass&& argOther)
{
  std::cout << "MyOtherClass move c'tor called.\n";
}

// Class MyClass
MyClass::MyClass(MyOtherClass&& arg)
: obj(std::move(arg)) 
{
  std::cout << "MyClass c'tor called.\n";
}
MyOtherClass& MyClass::getObjRef(void)
{
  return this->obj;
}
```

This code prints the output:

```
MyOtherClass c'tor called.
Address of getRValue local var is 0x7fff882a2db8
Returning from getRValue...
MyOtherClass move c'tor called.
MyClass c'tor called.
Address of bar member is 0x7fff882a2db0
```

My question is: why are the addresses of local var. and bar member different? Isn't it the whole point of move semantics that those two be the same? Or am I simply doing something wrong in my example?

Comment: "Isn't it the whole point of move semantics"? No it isn't. Move semantics moves the *content* of one object into another object. It does not somehow magically make two different object to become one. These are and will always be two different objects. Different objects will always have different addresses. In your example there is no genuinely *movable* content, which means that move semantics in your example always acts the same as copy semantics: all content is simply copied.

Comment: OK then, what makes an `std::vector` a movable content, and an `int` not? Should the content of data reside in heap somehow? Does this code only make sense when I have dynamically allocated array member inside `MyOtherClass`, and copy the pointer in move constructor, instead of an iterative deep copy?

Comment: Yes, you have the right idea. The fact that in a typical implementation `std::vector` stores a *pointer* to  its array of elements - that is what makes `std::vector` movable. In order to *move* the content of one vector into another you just need to *copy the pointer* to the recipient (and reset the source). This is where move semantics actually works: you have to store the content *indirectly*, as a "pointer" or a "handle". But when you store the content directly/immediately (as in your example), move semantics "does not work": it is reduced to ordinary copy semantics.

Comment: Is this behavior explicitly implemented in a `std::vector<T>(std::vector<T>&& other)` move constructor? Or is it handled implicitly?

Comment: @corsel It is explicitly coded by the devolpers

Comment: @corsel: It depends on the implementational details. If `std::vector` refers to its data by a *raw pointer* then it will have to implement its move semantics explicitly. If it uses some smart pointer instead, then the smart pointer might be able to handle it properly by itself. By in any case at some level it will boil down to a raw pointer and a manual implementation.

Comment: Move semantics moves the **state** of an object to another. It doesn't physically move one object to another address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every object has it's own address.  Since `bar` and `retVal` are different objects they have different addresses.  Moving does not change the address of the object.

What moving does is it allows you to move the guts of the object from one object into another.  Depending on how the class is made this can be a very big performance boost.  For instance if we have a class like a `std::vector` it is going to have a pointer in it to the storage it allocated.  Moving allows you to just copy the pointer and size from the moved from object to the moved to object.  Then you just set the pointer in the moved from object to a null pointer and set the size to 0.  Now we didn't have to copy any elements or allocate any storage which we would have had to do if we were making a copy instead.

Comment: So this is only useful when I implement a member pointer copy operation inside the move constructor, right? Like when I have a large dynamic array inside `MyOtherClass`, and instead of copying the contents one-by-one, I simply copy the pointer, and prevent destructor from being called?

Comment: @corsel That is where moving really shines.  Small caveat though, you don't stop the moved from object from being destroyed, you just put it into a state where it can be destructed without affecting the object you just moved the guts into.  In general moving is less than or equal to the cost of copying.

Comment: Umm well, say, the returned local object has a defined `~MyOtherClass`, in which its member pointers are `delete[]`d. It goes out of scope after return, now what? Does the compiler see that going out of scope, the contents are being moved, end elide the destructor call?

Comment: @corsel If you set the pointer to `std::nullptr` then `delete` and `delete[]` become non-ops.

Comment: @corsel The move constructor puts the moved from object in a state where it is safe to destruct and that destruction will not affect the moved to object.

Comment: @corsel moving is also very handy when you have a resource that cannot, for one reason or another, be duplicated.

Comment: I have no more questions :) Thanks for all the help. I'd been confused by how it can by-pass all calling conventions, stack pointers, etc. to transfer a local's ownership... The question looks very stupid after having got the answers.